# Glue metal bolt to nylon hole

Tags: metals

What type of glue is best used to glue stainless steel bolt (not screw) used as self tapping to a hole (no thread) in a 3d printed nylon (polyamide) part? It will be an M2 metric bolt.

Comment: Depends a lot on the expected stress, both magnitude and direction, as well as the expected operating environment (e.g. don't pick a glue that's water-soluble for an aquarium environment, or hot-glue for a 250 C environment).  The more detail you can provide, the better recommendations you'll get.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search with "adhesive for nylon to steel" presents a number of results, almost all of them indicating that there is a solution. Polypropylene/polyethylene adhesive in the form of an epoxy will bond to the nylon and also to properly prepared steel surfaces.

The preparation segment appears to be a critical factor. Cleanliness as well as surface roughness provides the best results. One would use an alcohol type cleaner, such as rubbing alcohol on both parts, to remove grease, skin oil, etc, but that should be performed after abrading the surfaces with 200-400 grit sandpaper.

This is not a product recommendation SE and it's impractical to suggest a specific product, as the search will also present suitable products, possibly specific to your area of the planet. For many in the USA, Loctite brand products cover a wide range of applications, including this one.